# Change applicationId or also package name?

Tags: android, android-manifest, package

Assume there is `applicationId com.example.application` in `build.gradle`. This name is shown after "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=". I want to change it to another, for instance, "org.domain.app". Should I also change `package name` in AndroidManifest and rename package folder? In https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html it is said that if have different `applicationId` and `package name`, there may be a problem with `WebView`. Also there and in https://blog.stylingandroid.com/package-name-vs-application-id/ it is said that after build `applicationId` is copied to AndroidManifest and change `package` attribute.

In order to have different APK's for each flavor `applicationId` can vary while `package name` remains the same.

So, have I set `package name` to `applicationId`? If not, what problems can occur?

Comment: `applicationId` overwrites `packagename` in manifest.

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub, it's interesting. Is it enough? By the way, last year we changed `package name` and `applicationId`.

Comment: The package `name` in the **AndroidManifest.xml** is overridden by `applicationId` in **build.gradle**. So Gradle replaces manifest one. Use `applicationId`

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub, thanks!

Comment: @YoushaAleayoub, I checked your answer, it really works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `applicationId` in Gradle build file will **overwrite** the `packagename` in the Manifest file.

Why do we need both of them?

- Because `packagename` is designed to organize your source code and your **R** class.
- And `applicationId`, is used in your device(application's settings), in Play Store and creating build variants.

*More information in docs: https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html*

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change applicationId nor package name of the app you publish, according to [this article](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/06/things-that-cannot-change.html).

You can, however, change them for any flavor you like as long as they are not published according to [this article](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-package-name-vs-application-id-ad95b08815a6)

Comment: App's name can change, that's right, but above things have to stay the same